# node.js - newbie mongojs issue

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongojs

I am trying to learn MongoJS, But its not working.
I wrote this code so far -

```
/* Basics */

var express = require('express'),
    app = express(),
    server = require('http').createServer(app),
    io = require('socket.io').listen(server),
    db = require("mongojs").connect("mydb", ["users"]);

server.listen(27017, null);

io.set('transports', ['xhr-polling']);

// routing
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.sendfile("index.html");
    app.use(express.static(__dirname));
});

db.users.save({username : "admin"}, function(err, saved) {
    if( err || !saved ) { console.log("User not saved"); }
    else { console.log("User saved"); }
});
```

It log to the console "User not saved", but why? what I did wrong?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are confused about ports and are trying to tell your web server to listen on port `27017`, which is the port mongodb listens on. Try `server.listen(3000)` (or another available port of your choosing). If you want to troubleshoot the `db.users.save` error, try printing the actually error message (`err`) to console and go from there.

Comment: Thank you! Now I log the error message `err` and it logs `Error: failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:27017` What I did wrong now?

Comment: No problem I fixed it.. I just needed to run mongo.exe..I Upvoted you and accepted your answer ;)